# Inserting an older date in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, date

tried this query for entry a two day older date

```
INSERT INTO `subject` (`id` ,`marks` ,`entry`)
VALUES ('12121', '12','CURRENT_DATE()-2');
```

it gives

```
    id  |  marks  |  entry
  12121     12      0000-00-00
```

also tried `'CURRENT_DATE() interval 2'`

Comment: `also tried 'CURRENT_DATE() interval 2'` How you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting a string into a date column.  The string gets converted to a number with a value of `0`.  Instead, try this:

```
INSERT INTO subject(id, marks, entry)
    SELECT '12121', '12', CURRENT_DATE() - interval 2 day;
```

Comment: Are `interval` and `day` required in MySQL or would `CURRENT_DATE() - 2` also work? (I come from an Oracle background where you'd simply do `SYSDATE - 2`)

Comment: @JonK:- You need to specify what you are trying to add or subtract ie, 2 day or 2 month! :)

Comment: @JonK . . . It is easy to make mistakes when doing arithmetic on MySQL date/times.  MySQL has this (irritating) feature of sometimes treating dates as numbers and not dates, so `select now() - 30` sort of subtracts 30 seconds.  And `CURRENT_DATE - 30` doesn't do what you think (today, it produces the number 20140788).  In any case, to prevent confusion, I use `interval` in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `subject`(`id` ,`marks` ,`entry`)
 SELECT '12121', '12', CURRENT_DATE() - interval 2 day;
```